# How can my arguments "not match any signature" of console.log?

Tags: typescript

A simple class:

```
export class Logger {
  constructor(private name: string) {}

  debug(...args: any[]) {
    console.debug(...args)
  }

  log(...args: any[]) {
    console.log(...args)
  }
}
```

As far as I know, I can pass literally anything to `console.log` and `console.debug`, so how come I'm getting:

```
src/app/logging.ts(6,5): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
src/app/logging.ts(10,5): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Doing `.apply(args)` works, but then what's the point of the `...args` syntax?

I'm using TypeScript version 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` is defined as

```
log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
```

Try switching to

```
export class Logger {
  constructor(private name: string) {}

  debug(msg?: any, ...args: any[]) {
    console.debug(msg, ...args)
  }

  log(msg?: any, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log(msg, ...args)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's very informative, I'll try that. But out of curiosity, how do you know what `console.log` is defined as?

Comment: @Hubro Typescript comes with definitions of standard libraries. In installed typescript look for directory `lib`. On github you can find it here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib and `console.log` specifically is here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L6472